# C- Structure within structure

Tags: c, structure

If i have these structures:

```
struct rec {
 int key;
 double value;
};

struct node {
 struct rec record;
 struct node *next;
};
```

and I have to copy the values of the fields of an item  `struct rec *r` into an item `struct node *n`,

can i do this?

```
n->record.key = r->key;
n->record.value = r->value;
```

Comment: The immediate answer is no, but only because your member is called `record`, not `rec`. Using correct member names, *yes*, you can do this, but there are better ways (see below).

Comment: You're right, now i've correct the text!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can make a copy of your `struct` one field at a time. You can also do it in a single shot:

```
struct rec *r = ...;
struct node *n = ...;
n->record = *r; // Copies the content of "r" into n->record
```

Doing it that way has the advantage of not having to revisit the copying code each time you modify the structure of `struct rec`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `rec` structure contains only fields of basic types, it is perfectly valid and reasonable to do:

```
n->record = *r;
```

which in this case is equivalent to copying `key` and `value` fields separately:

```
n->record.key = r->key;
n->record.value = r->value;
```

Comment: what is a PDO type? You mean POD? This is C and not C++.

Comment: @JensGustedt A postfix version of POD =P

Comment: @JensGustedt: Yah, that was a typo ^^ I've edited my answer to avoid further confusion though :)

Comment: Still your implicit reference to C++'s PODs makes no sense in the context of C. Here assignment of any structure type is a valid operation.

Answer (score -1):

```
n->rec.key = r->key;
n->rec.value = r->value;
```

Is correct but better is:

```
memcpy(&n->rec, r, sizeof n->rec);
```

Now You can expand struct rec with new fields without changing existing code

Comment: -1, I don't see why `memcpy` would be better than the copy operation that is foreseen by the language? Just do `n->rec = *r`.